# What does this method want as a parameter

Tags: java

I've been given code to work with and i need to use this method

```
    public <A extends Actor> List<A> getObjects(Class<A> cls) {
    ArrayList<A> someArray = new ArrayList<A>();
    for (Node n: getChildren()) {
        if (cls.isInstance(n)) {
            someArray.add((A)n);
        }
    }
    return someArray;
}
```

I understand what it returns and everything else just not the parameters it wants me to pass in and have been stumped for a while now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a class named `MyActor` that extends `Actor` and you want to call this method to get a `List<MyActor>`. Like,

```
List<MyActor> al = getObjects(MyActor.class);
```

Comment: I probably should've explained this a bit better the function is used to get all the objects in an FXML scene and run their act() functions on them, as it stands im not quite understanding how to implement your explanation with how my code is

Comment: What are `Node`(s)? `List<Node> al = getObjects(Node.class);` - as long as the class extends `Actor` and is castable to the subclass you pass it should work, but you asked how to call the function.

Comment: ohh okay sorry i understand it now, thanks for the patience ahah

Answer (score 0):

Your method takes any `class` as an argument which is extending your class `Actor` and returns a list of those `subclass's` objects.

For you to use this method you need below set up:

```
class MyActor extends Actor {
   // some internal logic
}
```

Then call your method by passing above class from your main method or any service as:

```
...
List<MyActor> actors = getObjects(MyActor.class);
...
```